# What's causing these image sizes to be wrong?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I cannot work out why some of the images on this page are wrongly sized (2 of them appear smaller than the others).

https://www.violinschool.org/video-testing/

I have re-cropped them all to the same size (355x200, ratio 16:9) so there must be something else causing it.

Am trying to check the html and CSS (it's a wordpress site using Toolset Types) to see what might be wrong, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line to your CSS file and see if it helps:

```
table.wpv-loop.js-wpv-loop td {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not in images but in `table`. Now each `table-cell` is taking dynamic width according to its content. If one `table-cell` has more content it will be wider than others.

Add `table-layout: fixed` property on `table` then all `table-cell` will take equal width and your problem will be fixed.

```
table {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `<td>` in table are not fixed width they get the width according to the content inside it untill the width is not defined in css.

You can do it with 2 solutions.

**First is** Add `table-layout:fixed` in table.

```
table{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

> Adding `table-layout:fixed` will restrict the table to show each cell with same width.

**and second** Use width in `<td>`

As you are using exact 4 `<td>` in one row so you can give width manually `width:25%`.

```
td {
    border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 0;
    width: 25%;
}
```